# React Native: cannot read / update app.json from app.config.js

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

[Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/) mention being able to read / change `app.json` contents from `app.config.js`. I am trying to set the Google Maps API Key from app.config.json (it is currently in `app.json`). But I cannot read it from `app.config.js`

`app.json`

```
{
 ...
  "android": {
    "config": {
      "googleMaps": {
        "apiKey": "xxx" //set this from app.congif.js in order to use .env variable
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`app.config.js`

```
export default ({ config }) => {
    
    console.log(config.android)
    //set key here
    
    return {
      ...config,
    };
  };
```

result from console.log is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Check if `"android"` attribute is under `"expo"` or not. The project I work with used to have `"android"` outside `"expo"`. I suppose expo doesn't differentiate under the hood, but while using `app.config.js` you can only access data inside the `"expo"` attr.